# Block type conflit

Tags: ios, block, objective-c-blocks

```
- while I was using a block, it aways prompt block type confit，
```

thereason as below：

```
 Redefinition of 'responseObject' with a different type: 'sucessBlock
 (__strong' (aka 'void (^__strong)(__strong id)') vs 'id _Nullable
   __strong' // here is the block declare： #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> typedef void(^sucessBlock)(id
   respondseObject); typedef void(^failureBlock)(NSError * error);


 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    typedef void(^sucessBlock)(id respondseObject);
    typedef void(^failureBlock)(NSError * error);
    @interface TRAFNetWorkManager : NSObject
    +(void)sendGetRequestWithUrl:(NSString*)urlStr paramenters:(NSDictionary*)paramDic sucess:(sucessBlock)suscess failure:(failureBlock)failure;
    @end
```

// here is the complement #import

```
  #import "TRAFNetWorkManager.h"
    #import "AFNetworking.h"
    @implementation TRAFNetWorkManager

    +(void)sendGetRequestWithUrl:(NSString *)urlStr paramenters:(NSDictionary *)paramDic sucess:(sucessBlock)suscess failure:(failureBlock)failure {
        AFHTTPSessionManager* manager=[AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        [manager GET:urlStr parameters:paramDic progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

            sucessBlock(responseObject);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

            NSError*error1=nil;
            failureBlock(error1);
        }];
    }

@end
```

Comment: Your code has several spelling errors - for example, variable name for `success` is spelled as `suscess` and `sucess`. Also `sucessBlock` should be `successBlock`.

Answer (score 2):

`successBlock` and `failureBlock` are names of block *types*. You cannot use them for invocation. Instead, you need to use names of block *variables*, which in your case are `success` and `failure`:

```
+(void)sendGetRequestWithUrl:(NSString *)urlStr
                 paramenters:(NSDictionary *)paramDic
                     success:(successBlock)success
                     failure:(failureBlock)failure {
    AFHTTPSessionManager* manager=[AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:urlStr parameters:paramDic progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSError*error1=nil;
        failure(error1);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Error has been found, block type was wrong,it must be parameter,thank you  !